# 'of' or 'by' renewable energy sources

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentence:

"The volatile electricity generation **of**  renewable energy sources like wind turbines is a challenge for the electricity grid"

Is it correct to use 'of' here? Or do I have to use 'by' (or anything else)?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: *Is it correct to use 'of' here?* It depends what you mean. "of" = associated with; "by" = by means of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***By*** means ‘as a means of’ something or someone. This preposition often comes in a passive sentence.

While ***Of*** expresses the relationship of a part of something to its whole.

In the passive voice, “by” indicates WHO is doing the action.
For example:- "David is cleaning the kitchen."

The above sentence in passive voice would be

"The kitchen is being cleaned by David."

Therefore.,
"The volatile electricity generation ***by*** renewable energy sources like wind turbines is a challenge for the electricity grid"

Comment: Thanks Alka Yadav for your answer and help